# How to change visibility/display of a html block using flask or vanilla js with submit event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask, heroku

I created a small flask app and deployed it on Heroku. I'm bad with backend and flask I just can't figure out how to properly display html block of code that should display under the form when it is submitted. 
Link to the app: http://alumil-alloys.herokuapp.com/ 
Link to github repo: https://github.com/nemanjaKostovski/MLmodel 
HTML:

```
<form class="form" action="{{ url_for('main') }}" method="POST">
        <label class="label"><input class="input" type="number" step="0.01" name="Rm" placeholder="Rm" required></label>
        <label class="label"><input class="input" type="number" step="0.01" name="Rp" placeholder="Rp" required></label>
        <label class="label"><input class="input" type="number" step="0.01" name="A%" placeholder="A%" required></label>
        <label class="label"><input class="input" type="number" step="0.01" name="Wb" placeholder="Wb" required></label>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
 <div class="result">
    {% if result %}
        {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
            <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <br> <h3>Suggested alloy:</h3>
           <p class="big">{{ result }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='main.js')}}"></script>
```

CSS:

```
    .result {
  visibility: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  background-color: #ffd300;
}
```

JS:

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const result = document.querySelector('.result');

function showResult(){
    result.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

form.addEventListener('submit', showResult);
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    if flask.request.method == 'GET':
        return(flask.render_template('main.html'))
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        max_strength = flask.request.form['Rm']
        yield_strength = flask.request.form['Rp']
        elongation = flask.request.form['A%']
        webster = flask.request.form['Wb']
        input_variables = pd.DataFrame([[max_strength, yield_strength, elongation, webster]],
                                       columns = ['Rm', 'Rp', 'A%', 'Wb'],
                                       dtype = float)
        prediction = model.predict(input_variables)[0]
        return flask.render_template('main.html',
                                     original_input = {'Rm':max_strength,
                                                     'Rp':yield_strength,
                                                     'A%':elongation,
                                                     'Wb':webster},
                                     result = prediction
                                     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I missed the fact that you were already returning your result as key word arguments (you were just doing it differently from me) so I'm going to edit the answer (deleted most of the previous answer and responding based on the information you have provided in a comment.

Based on your current design

1. The first time you load your page, the result div will not show up
2. Then you execute a search and the result div will show up. It may or may not contain results
3. The result div will now always be visible unless you reload the page. If you do a new search, the contents of the result div will be cleared

If you're okay with the above behavior, then you don't even need the JS script. Just modify your code to

```
{% if result %}
    <div class="result">
    ......
{% endif %}
```

You can do away with your JS and the visibility style in your CSS

The explanation is

1. When you load your page, the system executes a `GET` and your flask code says to return just the template without any variables. The page will thus check for `result` and since it is not available, it will not display the `result div`
2. Then you enter variables and submit the form which does a `POST` and your flask now returns a `result` variable which means the `result div` will now be displayed to the user
3. If user wants to clear the `result div` from the UI, they can reload the page or you can add a button or delete icon that when it is clicked, you remove the div from the page

Comment: Should I just put your code snippet at the end of my flask file, or should I replace a portion of my code with yours?

Comment: Just to mention, my app actually works, but when I started styling it the result part showed up from the beginning and I wanted to get rid of it before the actual form is submitted. So I was trying visibility and display options with few lines of JS. So my mistake also could be there, but it could also be somewhere in rendering the new information with js submit event. Whenever I submit form it loads and goes away fast, and visibility isn't switched from hidden to visible, but if you go to developer tools and switch of hidden, then it is as it should be.

Comment: I also tried preventDefault() in JS, which stops the page from reloading and then function showResult works, but flask then doesn't render result because it didn't reload. It's like JS and Flask negate each other in this case. Maybe I should use Django instead xD I don't like Flask anyway and I've never used it. Best case for me would be to use Node.js, but that probably can't happen? Maybe if I can somehow translate my ML model into JSON? This is a fairly simple app, but it's covering a lot of topics. That's why I want to make it work properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved my issue! I don't think a delete button is necessary in this app. It is a good addition just for the showcase, but it isn't important in this case. This is just a simple tool to give a suggestion what aluminium alloy should be used to achieve specific  mechanical properties of a material. Thanks again!